# Using custom CursorAdapter with LoaderManger initialize with null cursor

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I have created a custom CursorAdapter to use with my listview and implemented the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks functions to load data.

My problem: in my onCreate() method for my activity, I want to create an instance of my CursorAdapter and set it as the adapter for my listview. However, since the LoaderManger has not run my query and returned a cursor yet, I don't have a cursor to pass into the constructor for my adapter. If I pass in null I get a null pointer exception.

With simpleCursorAdapter you are able to pass a null cursor if it hasn't been initialized yet. But I extended CursorAdapter and it doesn't behave the same way.

My question: is there a way to pass a null cursor to my adapter? I get the exception when my constructor calls the super(context, cursor) method of my adapter. I don't do anything else in the constructor.

If I delay creating my adapter (and thus setting it as the adapter to the listview) until the onLoadFinished() call from the LoaderManger, everything works fine, but I am thinking that is not the best way to do this.

I also saw this link:

http://rajeevranganathan.blogspot.com/2012/07/creating-custom-cursor-adapter-and.html

where he re-creates the entire CursorAdapter every time, in essence swapping out the listview's adapter, not simply its cursor - this seems rather inefficient: you shouldn't have to recreate your adapter, just swap out the cursor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Am I just going to have to extend SimpleCursorAdapter and simply ignore all the additional arguments I don't need?

Thanks!

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` extends `CursorAdapter`... so if `SimpleCursorAdapter` is able to accept a `null` Cursor as an argument, then you should be able to create your own subclass that is also able to accept a `null` Cursor as an argument, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the CursorAdaptor constructor with a **autoRequery** parameter, and pass false, then passing a null cursor is ok:

```
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    MyCursorAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, null, false);    // cursor=null, autoRequery=false
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a bad thing to leave your ListView without an adapter. If you really want to give your SimpleCursorAdapter an empty cursor, I guess you could create a MatrixCursor with no rows.

Check out the [Loaders Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) on the Android dev pages.

Comment: Well, I'm just wondering how this will affect the activity behavior. I am loading from a local sqlite db so it all happens quite quickly right now, but if there gets to be a large volume of data how will the listview react upon initial load while it doesn't have a cursor? If it causes the UI to hang, then it really isn't better than just running query on the UI thread...

Comment: The advantage of the list adapter pattern is that the ListView/GridView/AdapterView recycles its views so that it only instantiates enough to fill the screen, and re-uses them as the user scrolls. Rows that are outside the current window only exist as rows in the Cursor. The Cursor maintains a connection to whatever data source is backing it, and it controls how much of that data set is actually in memory at a given time. If you drill down into a SQLiteCursor in the debugger, you can see exactly what it's doing.